# Indirect modification of overloaded property to modify post data

Tags: forms, yii

My goal is change a $_POST['url'] to save it in database with in front"tcp://".$_POST['url'].

$model = $this->loadModel($id);

```
if (isset($_POST['xxx'])) {     
    $model->attributes = $_POST['xxx'];
    $model->attributes['url'] = 'tcp://'.$_POST['xxx'];  <-
    if ($model->save()) {
```

but it return "Indirect modification of overloaded property " .
What the correct way to change that field?

Comment: You can do it 
    $model->ur = 'tcp://'.$model->ur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have two choices:

1) Because you used `$model->attributes = $_POST['xxx'];`, you can access the values in `$_POST['xxx']` as the model's attributes, so `$model->url = 'something';` will work.

2) Generally you can move the values you want to modify into a new variable, modify them there and overwrite the original value with the new variable. It is especially useful if you want to modify a related model, which results in the same error message you received.

The wrong way:

```
$model->relationSomething = new RelationSomething;
$model->relationSomething->someAttribute = 'newValue';
```

The code above will result in the error message you received.

The correct way:

```
$model->relationSomething = new RelationSomething;
$tempVariable = $model->relationSomething;
$tempVariable->someAttribute = 'newValue';
$model->relationSomething = $tempVariable;
//Optimally you want to save the modification
```

Using this method lets you modify attributes in related models without causing errors.